# Backup with verify gives CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an application that is performing an SQL backup of a database over the network. Working with SQL 2008 SP2 produces the following error.

```
An error has occured and the operation could not be completed successfully.

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in the database 'master'
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

10 percent processed.
...
Processed 68272 pages for database 'Db01', file 'Db01' on file 1.
100 percent processed.  
Processed 6 pages for database 'Db01', file 'Db01_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 68278 pages in 4.276 seconds

Please retry.
```

The backup file is however created but the message is misleading to users and they always assume the process was not completed successfully.

The sql server is running under a Network Service service and I have tried assigning permissions for the Network Service to the master database but it is still generating the errors.

Using SQL Server Management Studio to backup and verify the backup works fine without errors.

How can I prevent the error from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the backupset table to see what account is running the backup. Then issue `grant create database to [that login]` to give that login create database permissions (it's possible you may have to create the login first if it's gaining access through an AD group).